# Fetch product data from Play Store but I cannot make a purchase

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-in-app-purchase

I can fetch product data from Play Store with FlutterInappPurchase, but I cannot make a purchase. Follow for details;

I'm using **flutter_inapp_purchase**@2.2.0

I shared it on the go page of the module, but I want to reach a larger audience. Because I can't solve the insufficient resources.

The working process of my code;

- The purchase process takes place in the dialog.
- I read the dialog separate widget and the information used for the purchase (productId etc.) from my API service.
- I put this data in the variable `List<IAPItem> _items = []` in initStates, then I connect the plugin.
- Log I print to make sure I print. *I'm sure I can extract the data from the API!*

```
Setting.productLists:: [io.kr.english.course.purchase.all.3, io.kr.english.course.purchase.all.2, io.kr.english.course.purchase.all.1]
```

- return *consumeAllItems* log

```
I/flutter ( 3947): consumeAllItems error: PlatformException(consumeAllItems, refreshItem, No purchases found)
```

- But then my `_getProduct()` function works and I can see the products on the log screen.

  - Sample return product data log;

```
SUBSCRIPTION_ID:: productId: io.kr.english.course.purchase.all.1, price: 1.19, currency: TRY, localizedPrice: ₺1,19, title: 1 Aylık (Keyrote), description: 1 Aylık eğitim paketi, introductoryPrice: , introductoryPricePaymentModeIOS: , subscriptionPeriodNumberIOS: null, subscriptionPeriodUnitIOS: null, introductoryPricePaymentModeIOS: null, introductoryPriceNumberOfPeriodsIOS: null, introductoryPriceSubscriptionPeriodIOS: null, subscriptionPeriodAndroid: P1M, introductoryPriceCyclesAndroid: , introductoryPricePeriodAndroid: , freeTrialPeriodAndroid: , iconUrl: , originalJson: {"skuDetailsToken":"AEuhp4Ibjcl0f_I9C1Apvz79Dzgbd_tPs3Rn4vxtBF2dpLKwsnJYvyTR10Gc_CvI7Z2C","productId":"io.kr.english.course.purchase.all.1","type":"subs","price":"₺1,19","price_amount_micros":1190000,"price_currency_code":"TRY","subscriptionPeriod":"P1M","title":"1 Aylık (Keyrote)","description":"1 Aylık eğitim paketi"}, originalPrice: {"skuDetailsToken":"AEuhp4Ibjcl0f_I9C1Apvz79Dzgbd_tPs3Rn4vxtBF2dpLKwsnJYvyTR10Gc_CvI7Z2C","pr
```

- When I touch the button I made the purchase; It says "Oops; the item you tried to buy was not found" and when I touch the "OK" button in green, the logs are as follows;

```
W/ProxyBillingActivity( 3947): Activity finished with resultCode 0 and billing's responseCode: 4
W/BillingHelper( 3947): Couldn't find purchase lists, trying to find single data.
W/BillingHelper( 3947): Received a bad purchase data.
W/BillingHelper( 3947): Couldn't find single purchase data as well.
E/DoobooUtils( 3947): Error Code : 4
I/flutter ( 3947): purchase-error: responseCode: 4, debugMessage: , code: E_ITEM_UNAVAILABLE, message: That item is unavailable.
```

> Products are attached and active in google play.

There are not so many resources I could not solve. Thank you in advance for your help, I hope it was descriptive.

---

If I need to share the codes the same as what I found on the internet, you can follow them below.

**Connecting iAP to Service**

```dart
Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    String platformVersion;

    try {
      platformVersion = await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.platformVersion;
    } on PlatformException {
      platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    var result = await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.initConnection;
    print('result: $result');

    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _platformVersion = platformVersion;
    });

    try {
      String msg = await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.consumeAllItems;
      print('consumeAllItems: $msg');
    } catch (err) {
      print('consumeAllItems error: $err');
    }

    _conectionSubscription = FlutterInappPurchase.connectionUpdated.listen((connected) {
      print('connected: $connected');
    });

    _purchaseUpdatedSubscription = FlutterInappPurchase.purchaseUpdated.listen((productItem) {
      print('purchase-updated: $productItem');
    });

    _purchaseErrorSubscription = FlutterInappPurchase.purchaseError.listen((purchaseError) {
      print('purchase-error: $purchaseError');
    });

    await this._getProduct();
  }
```

**Fetching products**

```dart
Future _getProduct() async {
    List<IAPItem> items = await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.getSubscriptions(_productLists);
    for (var item in items) {
      print('SUBSCRIPTION_ID:: ${item.toString()}');
      this._items.add(item);
    }

    setState(() {
      this._items = items;
      this._purchases = [];
    });
  }
```

**Buy Product**

```dart
Future _buyProduct(IAPItem item) async{
    log.just("_buyProduct.item.id:: ${item.productId.toString()}");
    try {
      PurchasedItem purchased = await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.requestSubscription(item.productId);
      log.just("_buyProduct.purchased:: ${purchased.toString()}");
      String msg = await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.consumeAllItems;
      log.just("_buyProduct.msg:: $msg");
    } catch (error) {
      log.just('_buyProduct.catch:: $error');
    }
  }
```

**initState**

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _productLists = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < widget.pricingItemData.length; i++){
      _productLists.add(widget.pricingItemData[i]['product_id'].toString());
    }

    log.just('Setting.productLists:: ${_productLists.toString()}');

    initPlatformState();

    _pageController = new PageController(initialPage: 0);
    selectedIndex = 0;
  }
```

**Buy action code**

```dart
this._buyProduct(this._items[selectedIndex]);
```

**flutter doctor -v**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.17.0-3.2.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.778], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.17.0-3.2.pre at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 2a7bc389f2 (10 days ago), 2020-04-21 20:34:20 -0700
    • Engine revision 4c8c31f591
    • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.20.10)


[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0-rc2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\fatih\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 30.0.0-rc2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\fatih\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 45.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\fatih\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.9.1

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Venus GO   • 2811389118001055 • android-arm    • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)
    • Chrome     • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 81.0.4044.129
    • Web Server • web-server       • web-javascript • Flutter Tools

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: have you got the solution. Kindly refer solution to me, I need it too

Answer (score 0):

FlutterInappPurchase.instance.requestSubscriptions method require a second parameter on android:

/// Request a subscription on `Android` or `iOS`.

/// Result will be received in `purchaseUpdated` listener or `purchaseError` listener.

///
/// **NOTICE** second parameter is required on `Android`.
///

/// Identical to [requestPurchase] on `iOS`.

Future requestSubscription(String sku,
{
String oldSkuAndroid,
int prorationModeAndroid,
String developerIdAndroid,
String accountIdAndroid,
}) async {

```
if (_platform.isAndroid) {
  return await _channel
      .invokeMethod('buyItemByType', <String, dynamic>{
    'type': EnumUtil.getValueString(_TypeInApp.subs),
    'sku': sku,
    'oldSku': oldSkuAndroid,
    'prorationMode': prorationModeAndroid ?? -1,
    'developerId': developerIdAndroid,
    'accountId': accountIdAndroid,
  });

} else if (_platform.isIOS) {
  return await _channel.invokeMethod(
    'buyProduct', <String, dynamic>{
    'sku': sku,
  });
}

throw PlatformException(
    code: _platform.operatingSystem, message: "platform not supported");
```

}